# Adding space between the words

Tags: c++, visual-c++, state-machine

I am trying to add space to the file of a set of repeated words as follows. 
Basically a homework of State Machines. I have created the table in the array for it .

again, agony, bear, beat, can, caught, caused, me, more, morning, week, went, who, you

in a text file repeated 1000 times as

againagonybearbeatcancaughtcausedmemoremorningweekwentwhoyou

I don't know why it doesn't separte them whats wrong with it.

```
//A state machine to parse a sequence of known strings.

#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

  int counter;
// State Table for:
//      again, agony, bear, beat, can, caught, caused, me, more, morning, week, went, who, you
char NextState[27][31] = {
    // 0  1  2  3  4  5
1,  -1, 3,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 9,  -1, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
7,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 8,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 16, -1, 0,  -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, 25, 26, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, 2,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 14, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 28, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, 4,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 21, -1, 23, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
17, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  6,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 20, -1, 22, -1, -1, -1, 27, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, 5,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 18, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  30, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 19, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 15, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 12, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
25, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
30, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,

    //7, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1,  //1

};

//a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
char map[26] = { 0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 };

char state = 0;

void process(char ch)
{
    // print current char
    cout << ch;

    // move to next state
    state = NextState[map[ch - 'a']][state];

    // output a space if we are back to initial state
    if (!state) {
      cout << " ";
      counter++;
    }

}

int main(void)
{

    char ch;
    FILE * f;

    // open file for text input
    if (!(f = fopen("againTHRUyou.txt", "r"))) {
        printf("Cannot open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // read and display one byte at a time
    while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
    {
        process(ch);


    }

    cout<<"The count is " << counter <<endl;

    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: This state table hits me like a wall. ;-) I never thought about how to debug such hunk. However, it should be possible. This is how I would do it: 1. Draw [syntax diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram) to make it easier to follow the states. 2. Debug stepwise for a sample input. I would provide `me` or `meme` as sample input to make debugging less tedious. 3. Find out why your [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) doesn't reach state 0 as expected. (It is a DFA, isn't it?)

Comment: To prevent little accidents, it might be helpful to prefix table rows by comments with row index as well as you already started to for the columns. Such massive data is good for little mistakes in lookup which make debugging more annoying.

Comment: Please explain the "-1" in your table. If it is (as I guess) and explicit invalid value, which is checked against in the code, then I recommend to introduce an explicit "things-went-wrong" state, the index of which you use instead of the "-1". Maybe put it on index 0, to have a similarily obvious effect on the table. In that state you can do whatever makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

As this looks to be your college assignment, do not count on a complete answer here. I'll give you some hints instead.

Consider this line of your code:

```
state = NextState[map[ch - 'a']][state];
```

What are your assumptions about the code as it runs?

- What is the expected range of the first index into `NextState`? Is the actual argument always within the expected range?
- What is the expected range of the second index into `NextState`? Is the actual argument always within the expected range?

Answering these two questions should get you on the correct route. 
BTW, please get familiar with a debugger and assertions, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert

Another hint is an  observation that your code runs well most of the time and only sometimes fails. In such cases it is good to display the state of your program as it evolves. Add such "cout-debbugging" line just before and after the above line of code to see how your program changes the state.   For this to work, shorten your input file to about 100 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have time to closely examine your program. Here's a couple of observations:

- One problem is you made some mistakes in the state/event table. For instance, the state after the last letter in `"morning"` is `-1` **instead of `0`**:

  `-1, 2,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 13, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0/*-1*/, 0,  -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,`
- You **mix c & c++ styles**. Use `ifstream` instead of `FILE`:

  ```
  #include <fstream>
  //...
  ifstream is{ "c:\\temp\\test.txt" }; // opens the file; the file is automatically closed when the object goes out of scope
  if ( !is )
    return -1; // could not open

  char c;
  while ( is.get( c ) ) // get characters until the eof is reached or an error is encountered
  {
    //...
  }
  ```
- You do not test for invalid state (`-1`). Since this is a didactic application, it makes me believe the input is always valid, so you can ignore this. Once you reach the end of a word you must go back to state zero, so it makes sense to **initialize the table to `0`** (state zero), not to `-1`.
- Manually filling a state table is tedious and error prone. You must implement a **function that generates the table starting from a word**. For instance (not tested):

  ```
  enum
  {
    max_state = 50,
    max_event = 26
  };

  int table[ max_state ][ max_event ];
  int new_state = 0;

  int as_event( char c )
  {
    return c - 'a';
  }

  void add( const char* word )
  {
    const char* p = word;
    int state = 0;
    while ( *p )
    {
      int event = as_event( *p++ );
      int next_state = table[ state ][ event ];
      if ( next_state != 0 ) // path already exists: just use it
      {
        state = next_state;
        continue;
      }
      else // new path
      {
        next_state = ++new_state;
        table[ state ][ event ] = next_state;
        state = next_state;
      }
    }
  }

  void init()
  {
    memset( table, 0, sizeof table );
    add( "again" );
    add( "agony" );
    add( "bear" );
    // ...
  }
  ```